# morris chart not updating

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, morris.js

I have a problem with updating my `morris.js` bar chart.

When the page loads, I have the following function, which works fine and creates a nice chart:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.projectViewTotal').length) {
        chart = Morris.Bar({
          element: 'LastIncome',
          data: [
              { y: '04-02-2014', a: 3 },
              { y: '04-03-2014', a: 10 },
              { y: '04-04-2014', a: 5 },
              { y: '04-05-2014', a: 17 },
              { y: '04-06-2014', a: 6 }
            ],
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a'],
          labels: ['Visits']
        });
    };
});
```

Then after some user action I get new data via ajax and want to update my chart, but unfortunately after the update no data is shown in the chart and the labels are just `undefined`. I also get no error via the console.

and then I update the chart like this:

```
var response = $.parseJSON(content);
console.log(response);
chart.setData(response.jsString);
```

When I console.log my ajax answer I have this data structure for example:

`Object {jsString: "[ { y: '2014', a: 3505},{ y: '2013', a: 0},{ y: '2012', a: 0},{ y: '2011', a: 0} ]", sort: "getLastIncome"}`

But as I said I just get undefined labels and a chart with no data inside.

If I use `chart.setData()` width hard coded sample data everything also works fine. So it must be with the string I get from `response.jsString`, but I already used `$.parseJSON` on the callback, so I really don't know where the problem might be.

Do you have any ideas where the error might be? Thank you!

Here is my server side php code:

```
$ausgabeJS = "[ ";
$amount = count($data);
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if($i < $amount) {
       $ausgabeJS .= "{ y: '".$key."', a: ".$value."},";
    } else {
       $ausgabeJS .= "{ y: '".$key."', a: ".$value."}";
    }
    $i++;
}
$ausgabeJS .= " ]";
$responseArray = array(
   "jsString" => $ausgabeJS,
   "sort" => $method
 );
$result = json_encode($responseArray);
```

**SOLUTION**

Like JTG suggested, I had to change my server side code, to create a `numeric array` instead of a `string`. Here is the updated code:

```
$data_array = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $ar = array(
      "y" => $key,
      "a" => $value
   );
   array_push($data_array, $ar);
}
$responseArray = array(
   "jsString" => $data_array,
   "sort" => $method
);
$result = json_encode($responseArray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `response.jsString` is still a string, which isn't the accepted parameter for the `setData` function (it has to be an array of hash arrays).

Unfortunately, you can't JSON parse the `jsString` string because your keys aren't strings (which is a requirement for JSON) So make your keys strings, like so on your server side

```
{jsString: '[{"y": "2014", "a":2505}, {"y": "2014", "a":2505}, {"y": "2014", "a":2505}]', sort: "getLastIncome"}
```

And then you should be able to add the data to your graph

```
chart.setData($.parseJSON(response.jsString));
```

Let me know if that doesn't work

EDIT: Okay so we have two options.

First, you could change your php code to be

```
$data_return = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    array_push($data_return, array("y" => $key, "a" => $value));
}

$responseArray = array(
   "jsString" => $data_return,
   "sort" => $method
 );
$result = json_encode($responseArray);
```

I'm not certain this will work, I think it's worth a try because you aren't building a string that will have to be parsed twice.

But if that doesn't work, you can always go with my original suggestion and turn the keys of your hash array into strings themselves like so:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if($i < $amount) {
       $ausgabeJS .= "{ 'y': '".$key."', 'a': ".$value."},";
    } else {
       $ausgabeJS .= "{ 'y': '".$key."', 'a': ".$value."}";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

notice the extra single string quotes around the `y` and `a`.  Now the string you are building is proper JSON.  Now you should be able to do this.

```
var response = $.parseJSON(content);
console.log(response);
chart.setData($parseJSON(response.jsString));
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your answer. Which keys should be strings? You mean I shouldn't create an array on my server side, but just a combined string including `jsString` and `sort` and pass that one?

Comment: What you need to do is turn `"[ { y: '2014', a: 3505},{ y: '2013', a: 0},{ y: '2012', a: 0},{ y: '2011', a: 0} ]"` which is a string, into an array of hash values.  I don't know how to turn your string into an array of hash values easily without parseJSON, so my suggestion was to turn it into valid JSON (by turning the keys ie `y` and `a` into strings.  I don't know what your doing server side, or why `jsString` is a string at all....  But the end goal is the same, `jsString` is a string -- not an array of hash values and `.setData()` only takes an array of hash values -- not strings.

Comment: How are you creating the json on the server side?  Maybe we can fix the problem there...

Comment: I guess my problem is, that I use the same function I use to create the data used for the chart on page load, which is not gathered via ajax but echo's the data variable. I updated my question with the according code. Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out myself. See my updated question. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction! :)