# Morris Chart not working for data returned by ajax

Tags: javascript, charts

Here in below script if i run the part 2 which is current commented it will load static data and chart is displayed fine, but when i call the function delivery_by_owner() to load data dynamically i can't do it why??? data is coming exactly as i needed from ajax call. i can't update morris chart.

```
<script>

function delivery_by_owner()
{
    var from_date=$('#from_owner').val();
    var to_date=$('#to_owner').val();
    var transporter=$('#transporter').val();
    var vehicle=$('#vehicle').val();
    var response;
    console.log(vehicle);
    //alert(from_date+to_date+transporter+vehicle);
    $.post("ajax_handler.php",{"operation":"owner_graph","from":from_date,"to":to_date,"transporter":transporter,
    "vehicle":vehicle},function(data){
      response=$.parseJSON(data);

    });



{   
    Morris.Line({
  element: 'report2',
  data: [

                                for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
                                {
                                { y: response[i][0], a: response[i][1]},
                                }

  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
  labels: ['Total'],
  lineColors:['#1FB5AD']
});
}

}

////////////////// part 2  //////////////////////////
/*{ 
Morris.Line({
  element: 'report2',
  data: [
  { y: '23 Feb', a: 200, b: 160, c: 133},
    { y: '24 Feb', a: 200, b: 160, c: 133},
    { y: '25 Feb', a: 200, b: 160, c: 133},
    { y: '26 Feb', a: 200, b: 160, c: 133},
    { y: '27 Feb', a: 200, b: 160, c: 133},

    { y: '28 Feb', a: 200, b: 160, c: 133},
    { y: '29 Feb', a: 225, b: 200, c: 147},
    { y: '1 Mar', a: 231, b: 170, c: 160},
    { y: '2 Mar', a: 235, b: 175, c: 150},
    { y: '3 Mar', a: 228, b: 160, c: 130},
    { y: '4 Mar', a: 230, b: 130, c: 140},
    { y: '5 Mar', a: 245, b: 140, c: 160},
    { y: '6 Mar', a: 225, b: 150, c: 130},
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  labels: ['Total', 'Total', 'Total'],
  lineColors:['#1FB5AD', '#fc8675', '5ab6df']
});

}
*/</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching i found that we can't update graph content as above using loop in data, we can use setData() provided by morris charts to easily update chart content. One thing important to keep in mind is that we should provide data to .setData() in proper format and i found this link 
[morris chart not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768721/morris-chart-not-updating) 
 useful for understanding that.